# Having trouble with jquery and prev selector

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get it so that the previous checkbox is checked if one of the ones next to it is selected, for example...

I have a list of inputs like this:

```
<input class="options" type="checkbox" value="1" name="option[]">
<input class="inner_options" type="checkbox" value="1" name="inner_options[]">
<input class="inner_options" type="checkbox" value="2" name="inner_options[]">
<input class="options" type="checkbox" value="2" name="option[]">
<input class="inner_options" type="checkbox" value="3" name="inner_options[]">
<input class="inner_options" type="checkbox" value="4" name="inner_options[]">
```

and I want it so that if a user selects an inner_options checkbox then jquery will find the previous option and check it...if that makes sense?

I have this but it does not work:

```
$('.inner_options').click(function(){
   $(this).prev('.options').attr('checked',true);                 
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.prev()` selects the element's single previous sibling.

You want `.prevAll` to find all matching prior siblings.

Comment: I have tried doing this, but no such luck :(

$(this).prevAll('input[class="options"]').attr('checked',true);